# Fivem esplugin_mysql error while starting server

Tags: javascript, mysql, lua

I downloaded `mysql-async`, `essentialmode`, `esplugin_mysql`, `es_admin2`, `async` and it shows this error.

What is it about? Please help me I am trying to create my server.

```
    [ERROR] connect ETIMEDOUT
    Connecting: kworthbati
    Sending heartbeat to live-internal.fivem.net:30110
    [ERROR] [MySQL] [esplugin_mysql] An error happens on MySQL for query 
    "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `identifier`='steam:1100001337cd964';": 
    connect ETIMEDOUT
    Error running call reference function for resource esplugin_mysql: 
    citizen:/scripting/lua/scheduler.lua:355: @esplugin_mysql/server.lua:16: 
    attempt to index a nil value (local 'users')
    stack traceback:
    @esplugin_mysql/server.lua:16: in upvalue 'ref'
    citizen:/scripting/lua/scheduler.lua:341: in function 
    <citizen:/scripting/lua/scheduler.lua:340>
    [C]: in function 'xpcall'
    citizen:/scripting/lua/scheduler.lua:340: in function 
    <citizen:/scripting/lua/scheduler.lua:339>
    stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    citizen:/scripting/lua/scheduler.lua:355: in function 
    <citizen:/scripting/lua/scheduler.lua:324>
    Error: Unhandled error in timer: Error: BUFFER_SHORTAGE
    Error: BUFFER_SHORTAGE
    at n.e [as reserve] (citizen:/scripting/v8/msgpack.js:29:12766)
    at h (citizen:/scripting/v8/msgpack.js:29:15761)
    at n.r [as decode] (citizen:/scripting/v8/msgpack.js:29:13908)
    at n.fetch (citizen:/scripting/v8/msgpack.js:29:6972)
    at n.u [as read] (citizen:/scripting/v8/msgpack.js:29:12076)
    at Object.n [as decode] (citizen:/scripting/v8/msgpack.js:29:7097)
    at unpack (citizen:/scripting/v8/main.js:20:33)
    at citizen:/scripting/v8/main.js:51:20
    at setImmediate (mysql-async.js:14431:7)
    at Object.callback (citizen:/scripting/v8/timer.js:96:21)
```

Comment: Server configuration/installation is considerd [offtopic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here, reask the question on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

Your connection is timing out, likely due to the fact you do not have the correct port/IP of your SQL database or alternatively port/connection is blocked. Troubleshoot your connection by attempting to connect to the SQL DB by using HeidiSQL, and make sure your IP/PORT/CREDENTIALS match.